# Copy, Cut, Paste, Rename, Undo and Redo in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a window that has two widgets as QTreeView and QListView. I select a folder in QTreeView and show its contents in QTreeView.

```
void MainWindow::ListDirectory(QString arg_smb_path)
{
    o_directorySystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    o_directorySystemModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs);
    o_directorySystemModel->setRootPath(arg_smb_path);

    ui->treeView->setModel(o_directorySystemModel);
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(1);
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(2);
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(3);


    o_fileSystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    o_fileSystemModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files);
    o_fileSystemModel->setRootPath(arg_smb_path);

    ui->listView->setModel(o_fileSystemModel);
    ui->listView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(ui->listView, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)), this, SLOT(ShowContextMenu(const QPoint&)));
}
```

Also, I have a popup menu when I hover the mouse over the QListView.

```
void MainWindow::ShowContextMenu(const QPoint &arg_pos)
{
    // for QAbstractScrollArea and derived classes you would use:
    // QPoint globalPos = myWidget->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos);
    QPoint l_globalPos = ui->listView->mapToGlobal(arg_pos);

    QMenu l_contextMenu;
    l_contextMenu.addAction("Copy");
    l_contextMenu.addAction("Cut");
    l_contextMenu.addAction("Paste");
    l_contextMenu.addAction("Rename");
    l_contextMenu.addAction("Attribute");

    QAction* l_selectedItem = l_contextMenu.exec(l_globalPos);
    if (l_selectedItem)
    {
        // something was chosen, do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // nothing was chosen
    }
}
```

I wanted to know how can I make a copy, cut, rename, undo, and redo possible too. I wanted to select a file in listView and then try this operation on that file. How can I implement such action?

Comment: Study the source code of some open source Qt application providing copy & paste. See [KDE](https://kde.org/), it uses Qt. Spend a week in reading the documentation and examples of [Qt](https://www.qt.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) offers copy, remove, rename and moveToTrash functions which you can use to implement the file manipulation you wanted.

To implement your copy/cut and paste actions, you can save the filepath on copy in some variable as well as a bool `copyFile` (as opposed to moving), and within the paste action you (can) clear that variable after executing `QFile::copy()`

To implement your undo/redo functionality, Qt offers the [QUndoStack](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundostack.html). Basically you create [QUndoCommands](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundocommand.html) for each action (copy, rename, etc.) which provide undo() and redo() functions. For example the copy action corresponds to a QUndoCommand which copies on redo() and deletes the copy on an undo().

So in the end you will end up with a bunch of classes inheriting QUndoCommand:

- CopyCommand (which will save the selected filepath for a later paste, or reset the clipboard on an undo)
- CutCommand (same as CopyCommand, but setting `copyFile` to false, these could be the same class with a member)
- RenameCommand (which will rename on a redo() and rename with flipped values on an undo())
- PasteCommand (which will use the current `filePath` and `copyFile` values, again this command can probably use the same class as the rename)

Your undo and redo actions then simply call `undo()` and `redo()` on the stack. Have a look at both class descriptions to see how you can implement all this.

Comment: Is there any code example to learn these things? I try it but I could not implement it.

Comment: Apart from the class description, you will find some examples shipped with Qt. If you use the Qt Creator, you can click on `Welcome` in the top left and then on `Examples`, top left as well. There you find heaps and heaps of examples as well as a searchbar. Searching "Undo" will provide you some examples to check out. If you don't use the creator, examples are online [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html) as well.